SENDGRID - Response forbidden access when trying to creat webhook event through api
I am trying to create a sendgrid webhook, but I got 403 forbidden, although I had create my api key with full access
403 forbidden error
Firstly, I create a api with full access to the api, then I follow the document to create a webhook, but I get a 403 forbidden access.
My request body
I think I should be success full because my API key has full access to to sendgrid API.
Here is my apikey setup
enter image description here

Finished, It worked after lunch.
Maybe we need to wait a little bit time for key applied

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.
